# Rails mailchimp usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, mailchimp

I'm trying to send an email from my rails website which should use a mailchimp template with placeholders for the recipient's name etc. The reciemt's email adress should, as well as the other data, not be grabbed not from the mailchimp db, but from the rails site. At least I think it should be this way because the emails would be sent not too long after the users sign up so I wouldn't have time to import the email adresses. Additionally the email should have an pdf attachment.

The only gems I was able to find seem work in a different way. Can I use mailchimp this way at all? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using mandrill? Mandrill is the transactional email API of Mailchimp. This is probably what you are looking for:

http://rubygems.org/gems/mandrill-api